# How to dynamic change a view's width and height in android?

Tags: android, view, viewgroup

In my chat program, in order to show the length of the voice, I use a custom `LinearLayout` to display for users, it has two `TextView` ,one is to show how much time the voice has, the other is to show how long the voice is,

For example: a 10s length voice's `TextView` width is `20dp`, a 5s length voice's `TextView` width is `10dp`.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
textView.getLayoutParams().height = 50;
textView.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
```

Or if you want to assign values in dp than you can specify height and width values in dimen file and can do it this way:

```
textView.getLayoutParams().height = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textview_height);
textView.getLayoutParams().width = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textview_width);
```